# How to search and replace text in an xml file with SED?

Tags: bash, sed

I have to convert a list of xml files in a folder from UTF-16 to UTF-8, remove the BOM, and then replace the keyword inside the file from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

I'm using cygwin to run a bash shell script to accomplish this, but I've never worked with SED before today and I need help!

I found a SED one liner for removing the BOM, now I need another for replacing the text from UTF-16 to UTF-8 in the xml header.

This is what I have so far:

```
  #!/bin/bash
mkdir -p outUTF8

#Convert files to unix format.
find -exec dos2unix {} \;

#Use a for loop to convert all the xml files.
for f in `ls -1 *.xml`; do
    sed -i -e '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' FILE
    iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 $f > outUTF8/$f
    sed 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' $f > outUTF8/$f
    echo $f
done
```

However, this line:

```
sed 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' $f > outUTF8/$f
```

is hanging the script. Any ideas as to the proper format for this?

Comment: why don't you do `sed -i 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' outUTF8/$f` instead of `sed 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' $f > outUTF8/$f`

Comment: it's not the only issue, but change `for f in \`ls -1 *.xml\`; do` to `for f in *.xlm` and `$f` to `"$f"`

Comment: Yep, I agree that will prevent it from spliting files having spaces in them. Also, `sed -i -e '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' FILE` I don't really know what `FILE` is and it's purpose?

Comment: FILE isn't supposed to be there.  I took it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
for filename in *.xml; do
    sed -i".bak" -e '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$filename"
    iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$filename" > outUTF8/"$filename"
    sed -i 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' outUTF8/"$filename"
done
```

The first `sed` will make a backup of your original files with an extension `.bak`. Then it will use `iconv` to convert the file and save it under a newly created directory with same filename. Lastly, you will make an in-file change with `sed` to remove the text.

Comment: Well, everything almost worked.  I still have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> in the header of the files.  I need it to be <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> as that is what the file is converted to.  The script is no longer hanging though, it's running though to the end.

Comment: try using lower case in the last `sed` line, i.e use this `sed -i 's/utf-16/utf-8/g' outUTF8/"$filename"`

Comment: I took out all the uppercase and made it: sed -i 's/UTF-16/UTF-8/g' out/"$filename", but it's still not replacing the text.  I checked the file properties and there are no permissions problems.

Comment: `sed` is case-sensitive. So if the text you are intending to substitute is in lower case i.e `utf-16` then the `sed` script should use lower case in the command. Or you can add `i` before `g` to make substitution case-insensitive.

Comment: Alternatively you can also do the sed substitution before you convert the file.

Comment: After you had mentioned case sensitive, I changed it to: sed -i "s/utf-16/utf-8/g" out/"$filename" and it worked!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

2 things

1. How big is your $f file, if it's really really big, it may just take a long to complete.
2. Opps, I see you have an `echo $f` at the bottom of your loop. Move it before the sed command so you can see if there any spaces in the filenames.

2a:-). OR just change all references to `$f` to `"$f"` to protect against spaces.

I hope this helps.

Comment: if there are spaces in file names, the for loop will fail as well in this shape.

Comment: ok so size doesn't seem like it is the problem. do your filenames have spaces in them? @JaypalSingh looks to have all our current issues. Does this resolve your problem or does your code still hang.  Good luck.

Comment: Filenames don't have spaces, but all of them do have dashes and underscores in them.

Comment: So, it's still 'hanging'? Did you try using `set -vx` at the top of your script to see the expansion of each line. Try adding `--` on the sed line that  hangs just before where the filename is like `sed -i".bak" -e '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' -- $filename` . Good luck.